# How to know if my ipynb is actually running?

Tags: jupyter

When I run heavy machine learning algorithms, sometimes, nothing displays for quite awhile. I use `tqdm` or `print()` to indicate every time a step is finished. However, sometimes it takes an hour or more to even get one of those on screen.

I can tell something is running, using `top`, `free` or simply opening `Running` tab on Jupyter. But, I am unsure if those are just in a troublesome loop, frozen, or whatever wasting computing capacity.

I am wondering this because usually in those cases, if I leave them for the night and comeback, an error message is there! (Usually, memory error.) And I can't do anything until I see it since the process is using all the computing power.

Would there be a way to figure if my ipynb process is actually working?

p.s. I'm sorry if this is a ridiculous question or way far from the site's purpose. I'm kinda self-taught and face new disturbing - to me - basic things that I don't know on weekly, monthly basis. When googling doesn't help, I don't know where to ask but here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [notify extension](https://github.com/ShopRunner/jupyter-notify) which send a notification to the browser after the kernel has finished executing the current cell or in other words kernel becomes idle.

It is also available with [jupyter ipython extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions).

Answer (score 1):

Check on the right above corner. There is written python2 or 3 and a small circle. If you put your cursor there u can see it says its busy. Also, the block in which you are running the code it shows asterisk sign if its busy. Please accept and tick mark if it helps.